# How are Toloka task pages created

Tags: pool, toloka

I've uploaded a file with tasks to a pool, but the pool page has 0 task pages and the pool doesn't start. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload individual tasks, Toloka automatically groups tasks into sets. For example, if "smart mixing" (the mixer_config key for the pool) is set to 7 main tasks, 2 control tasks, and 1 training task, and you only uploaded the main tasks, the system won't be able to generate task pages using the configuration you set. Upload all types of tasks you are using in the pool or change the mixer settings to start the pool.